# Target span within MUI's ListItemText component to apply styles through useStyle hook

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

It's a very simple operation in regular CSS, but this needs to be done through MUI's useStyles for some reason or another.

Basically I have a `ListItem` with a `ListItemText` within it. Looks like the following:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    return (
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText primary={'blablablabla'}/>
      </ListItem>
    )
}
```

The thing is, I need to apply some styles ton the `ListItemText` that will only affect the text itself, for example change its color to red. If I were to use SCSS it would look something like the following:

```
.MuiListItemText-root {
   span {
      color: red;
      // other stuff
   }
}
```

However, this has to be done through `useStyles`. I currently do the following:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    redText: {
        color: 'red'
    }
}

...

const MyComponent = () => {
   const classes = useStyles() // Now, how do I use this on ListItemText???

    return (
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText primary={'blablablabla'}/>
      </ListItem>
    )
}
```

As mentioned above, the issue now is how to get it be applied to ListItemText where it needs to be. I have tried the following to no success:

- Using className

```js
return (
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText className={classes.overflow} primary={'blablablabla'}/>
      </ListItem>
    )
```

- Using classes:

```js
return (
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText classes={{root: classes.overflow}} primary={'blablablabla'}/>
      </ListItem>
    )
```

I've also tried different selectors within the useStyles declaration, attempting to incorporate MuiTypography, but nothing works:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    '>.MuiTypography-root': { // (tried many variations, this was just the latest)
        redText: {
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work and I am at my wits' end. How do I target inner components for styling with the MUI useStyles hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/)

Suppose I was using the wrong combination of selectors. Instead of requiring the `>`, I required the `&`. So for this case, it was solved by the following block of code:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    redText: {
        '& span': {
            color: 'red'
        }
    }
}
```